# Why is there a small white space between tiles in Chrome?

Tags: openlayers-2, web-mapping, google

I'm using openlayers to display a google base-map layer and it works fine on Firefox/IE/Safari. I'm having problems with Chrome as the tiles have a small white space between them shown in this image.

[image]

I found this [discussion](http://drupal.org/node/683636) about invasive CSS which suggested the problem was  due to

> Your theme is "helpfully" adding margins to img tags. you can override
>   this with

```
.openlayers-map img{ margin:0px }
```

I'm unclear where I put this line. I read through the openlayers CSS file but I don't have a good idea what is going on, on where I should be editing the `img` tag.

Comment: I had this problem and as @tmcw said is because of the zoomm of the page (not the map) in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two possibilities. The more likely is that you have Chrome zooming the page in or out, which introduces the white lines. Do cmd-0 (or ctrl-0) and see if that fixes it.

Otherwise, add that line to your CSS file, which might be site.css or whatever. Add it to the bottom, though it doesn't matter much. A live example would make this question easier to fix / diagnose.

Comment: Nicely spotted - it was due to zooming. Thank you.

Comment: This behaviour isn't unique to Openlayers, I see the same with ESRI ArcGIS Javascript API and zooming in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

That's something that has to do with Open Layers 2.12 and above, regarding the way that deals with the image tiles. I tried different things related to CSS and nothing changed. In my case, we decided to keep with Open Layers 2.11. and the white space were gone.

Answer (score 0):

I think that some where a Round() is used instead of Floor(). That makes the tile shift a sigle pixel and makes these lines appear.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me. Reverting to 2.11 has corrected.